# Mininet link error: "*** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory"

Tags: 16.04, networking

I am running [Mininet](http://mininet.org) (a network emulator) on Ubuntu 16.04.2. I created a Python file to create an emulated network (as the diagram shows in lines 6 and 7 in the file), named `topo001.py` that contains the following code:

```
"""
Topology001 created by zim7563

Three directly connected switches plus a host for only two switches:

   host1 --- switch1 --- switch2 --- host2
                \--switch3--/

Adding the 'topos' dict with a key/value pair to generate our newly defined
topology enables one to pass in '--topo=mytopo' from the command line.

In command line, enter: sudo mn --custom /home/network-research/Desktop/topo001.py --topo mytopo --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --link=tc

"""

import pdb
from mininet.topo import Topo
# Next two provide performance limiting and isolation features
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
# Additional (testing to see what may be needed to make it work)
#from mininet.net import Mininet
#from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
#from mininet.log import setLogLevel

class MyTopo( Topo ):

    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        S1 = self.addSwitch( 's1' )
        S2 = self.addSwitch( 's2' )
        S3 = self.addSwitch( 's3' )
        H1 = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        H2 = self.addHost( 'h2' )
        SwitchList = (S1,S2,S3)

        # Add links
        self.addLink( H1, S1 )
        self.addLink( S1, S2, bw=10)#, delay='5ms', loss=2, max_queue_size=1000, use_htb=True )
        self.addLink( S1, S3 )#, bw=20 )
        self.addLink( S2, S3 )
        self.addLink( H2, S2 )


topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

To run this file in Mininet, I enter the command `sudo mn --custom /home/network-research/Desktop/topo001.py --topo mytopo --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --link=tc` directly into the terminal (the file is saved on my Desktop). Upon doing so, Mininet starts and provides me with the following:

```
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
s1 s2 s3 
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s2) (10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(s1, s2) (s1, s3) (s2, s3) 
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 
*** Starting controller
c0 
*** Starting 3 switches
s1 s2 s3 ...(10.00Mbit) (10.00Mbit) 
*** Starting CLI:
```

The error message `*** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory` is given when other link parameters are set, also. (Other link parameters that I have tried are commented out after the pound (#) symbol in the file.) The only way to prevent this error message to occur is to remove all link parameters. This is not an option, however, because I need to set certain parameters for each link in the network.

I have scoured all over trying to find an answer but nothing has resolved this issue yet. I have uninstalled Mininet and then reinstalled it using the source code and I have rebooted my computer multiple times (before and after installing the source code version).

When I perform a `pingall`, all pings are successfully sent and received:

```
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> h2 
h2 -> h1 
*** Results: 0% dropped (2/2 received)
```

My question to you is: **In what ways can I resolve this error message?** Answer is given below and additional notes are provided in the updated section at the bottom of this post.

Secondary question: **Does this error prevent the links from acting as they are supposed to, given the parameter restraints?** Answer is unknown.

---

**Step-By-Step Solution Update:**

The solution listed below worked for me. Thank you juejiang! I uninstalled  my current version of Mininet and went to the master branch on GitHub found [here](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/INSTALL) and followed the instructions in part 3.1 about the "Native installation from source on Ubuntu 12.04+".

After the installation had completed, I rebooted my computer, started up my OpenDaylight controller, and then ran Mininet with my custom topology. The following is the *error free* result:

```
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
Connecting to remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6653
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
s1 s2 s3 
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s2) (10.00Mbit) (10.00Mbit) (s1, s2) (s1, s3) (s2, s3) 
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 
*** Starting controller
c0 
*** Starting 3 switches
s1 s2 s3 ...(10.00Mbit) (10.00Mbit) 
*** Starting CLI:
```

I then ran a `pingall` command and received the following:

```
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> h2 
h2 -> h1 
*** Results: 0% dropped (2/2 received)
```

Thanks again juejiang!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'v faced with this problem in ubuntu 14.04 too.
After I reinstall mininet from source (the master branch), the error message does not appear.
check the following line in link.py to make sure the code is updated.
 -         if "priomap" not in tcoutput:
 +        if "priomap" not in tcoutput and "noqueue" not in tcoutput:

```
https://github.com/mininet/mininet/pull/603
https://github.com/mininet/mininet/pull/629
```